# Why is this not compiling

Tags: c#

I have a library I need and it is written in c# from:

https://github.com/KarlPan/jsxbin-to-jsx-converter

I have read some of the basic c# documentation how to compile and the main terms from Microsoft website.

I have installed the following visual studio and the following build tools:

[image]

[image]

I have downloaded the source code and have run the command from commandline:

```
MSBuild.exe [mydirectory]/jsxbin_to_jsx.sln
```

But I get the following errors:

[image]

Or in text:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBui
ld\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBu
ild\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\
Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MS
Build\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(9,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.
0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(15,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\M
SBuild\14.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
  JsxbinToJsxTests.cs(15,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14
.0\Bin\jsxbin-to-jsx-converter-master\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests\jsxbin_to_jsx.Tests.csproj]
```

Googling the error I have tried to add the unit testing libraries using the `using` keyword inside of the project.cs file, but it still did not work. I have tried some other things but have been unable to get it to work.

Comment: Have you restored NuGet packages for the project? Do you have the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` nuget package referenced in your package.config?

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with the community addition of visual studio your using.  I've never used 2017 community, but the previous versions had limited or no support for unit tests.  Do you need to run the tests? If not you should be able to just build the project. Open the solution in visual studio, right click on the jsxbin_to_jsx project and click build.  See if you still get the errors.

Comment: @JonathonChase there is no package.config in projects at all :D (see git)

Comment: Don't include images of text. It's impossible to read. Copy and paste the text instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick test, you can download visual studio 2013/2015 to try with this solutions.

Because I just scan the documentation and see that last commit is about 3 years ago. You might give old version VS a try instead of new version.

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned it in Visual Studio 2015 and it built no problem. If you don't have a license for Visual Studio, try to download the trial or community version and do a quick test as Kira recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Just double-click the solution file (jsxbin_to_jsx.sln) to open it in Visual Studio. Then go Build -> Build Solution.